# Switching selectInput entry doesn't render what expected

Tags: r, shiny

In a modalDialog, I have a selectInput with some dates

For each date I have a dataframe with item ID and a value. All data are in a list `myhist` looking like this :

```
> myhist
$`2023-02-06`
  id  value
1  1 value1
2  2 value2

$`2023-02-05`
  id  value
1  4 value4
2  5 value5
3  6 value6
```

In my modalDialog, when I choose the first date 2023-02-06, it prints the list of my 2 values with a minus icon for each line to remove this specific line.

If I choose the second date 2023-02-05, it prints the list of my 3 values in the same way as above, all is working fine.

For this date 2023-02-05 if I remove the second element (id=5, value=5) by clicking the minus icon, it disappears...ok !

If I switch now to the other date 2023-02-06 with the selectInput, it prints ONLY the first element of the list. The second element is not displayed ! I think it is related to the second element I removed from the other date. But I don't understand why because in my code I apply a `removeUI` to the whole div content of elements then I built it again with the `apply` so all elements should be displayed ! Why one is missing ???

If I swich to the 2023-02-05 date THEN to the 2023-02-06 date so now the list is well displayed.

I tried to add `immediate=TRUE` to the `removeUI` but it doesn't work...

Here is a reproducible piece of code

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("open", "Modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  myhist <- reactiveVal(
    value=list("2023-02-06"=data.frame(item=c(1,2),value=c("value1","value2")), 
               "2023-02-05"=data.frame(item=c(4,5,6),value=c("value4","value5","value6"))
              )
  )
  count <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$open, {
    dates <- names(myhist())
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        tagList(
          selectInput(
            "dateList", "History:",
            choices = dates
          ),
          div(
            id = "add_update",
          )
        ),
        footer = tagList(
          modalButton("Cancel"),
          actionButton("add_db", "SAVE")
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  add_item <- function(count, item, value) {
    id <- paste0("gcs",count)
    idrm <- paste0("gcsrm",count)
    return(
      tagList(
        div(id=idrm,

                actionButton(inputId = id, icon("circle-minus"))
            ,
            div(textInput(width=164, inputId = paste0("add_id",count), "ID", value=item)),
            div(textAreaInput(width=400, height=100, inputId = paste0("add_comment",count), "Value",value=value))
        )
      )
    )
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$dateList, {
    mydf <- myhist()[[input$dateList]]
    removeUI(selector = "#add_update div", multiple=TRUE, immediate=TRUE)
    count(0)
    lapply(1:nrow(mydf), function(row) {
      insertUI(selector = "#add_update", ui = add_item(count(), mydf[row,]$item, mydf[row,]$value))
      id <- paste0("gcs",count())
      idrm <- paste0("gcsrm",count())
      observeEvent(input[[id]], {
        removeUI(selector = paste0("#", idrm))
      })
      count(count()+1)
    })
  })           
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanx for your help !

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are reusing the `id` and `idrm` for different dates.  By adding one more variable, you can make it unique.  Try this

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("open", "Modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  myhist <- reactiveVal(
    value=list("2023-02-06"=data.frame(item=c(1,2),value=c("value1","value2")), 
               "2023-02-05"=data.frame(item=c(4,5,6),value=c("value4","value5","value6"))
    )
  )
  count <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$open, {
    dates <- names(myhist())
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        tagList(
          selectInput(
            "dateList", "History:",
            choices = dates
          ),
          div(
            id = "add_update",
          )
        ),
        footer = tagList(
          modalButton("Cancel"),
          actionButton("add_db", "SAVE")
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  add_item <- function(count, date, item, value) {
    id <- paste0("gcs",count,date)
    idrm <- paste0("gcsrm",count,date)
    return(
      tagList(
        div(id=idrm,
            
            actionButton(inputId = id, icon("minus"))
            ,
            div(textInput(width=164, inputId = paste0("add_id",count), "ID", value=item)),
            div(textAreaInput(width=400, height=100, inputId = paste0("add_comment",count), "Value",value=value))
        )
      )
    )
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$dateList, {
    mydf <- myhist()[[input$dateList]]
    removeUI(selector = "#add_update div", multiple=TRUE, immediate=TRUE)
    count(0)
    lapply(1:nrow(mydf), function(row) {
      insertUI(selector = "#add_update", ui = add_item(count(),input$dateList, mydf[row,]$item, mydf[row,]$value))
      id <- paste0("gcs",count(),input$dateList)
      idrm <- paste0("gcsrm",count(),input$dateList)
      # print(id)
      # print(idrm)
      observeEvent(input[[id]], {
        removeUI(selector = paste0("#", idrm))
      })
      count(count()+1)
    })
  })           
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at my issue but your solution is not fully working. When the modalDialog is open with the default date 2023-02-06, if I remove the ID 2 and choose the other date 2023-02-05, all elements are present now  but if I choose back the first date 2023-02-05 in the list, the element I removed first time is missing. If I change the date in the list, the list must be like in the original list

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to avoid the bias explained in my previous comment.

I used as @YBS another unique id (based on Sys.time() with 6 digits for sec) for wrapping all my lines item/value. So now when I delete a line for a date then choose another date, all items appears as they do. Here is my reproducible code. Thanx for the clue.

```
library(shiny)
options(digits.secs=6)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("open", "Modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  myhist <- reactiveVal(
    value=list("2023-02-06"=data.frame(item=c(1,2),value=c("value1","value2")), 
               "2023-02-05"=data.frame(item=c(4,5,6),value=c("value4","value5","value6"))
    )
  )
  count <- reactiveVal(0)
  addupdate <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$open, {
    dates <- names(myhist())
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        tagList(
          div(id="mainupdate",
            selectInput(
              "dateList", "History:",
              choices = dates
            )
          )
        ),
        footer = tagList(
          modalButton("Cancel"),
          actionButton("add_db", "SAVE")
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  add_item <- function(count, date, item, value) {
    id <- paste0("gcs",count,date)
    idrm <- paste0("gcsrm",count,date)
    return(
      tagList(
        div(id=idrm,
            actionButton(inputId = id, icon("minus")),
            div(textInput(width=164, inputId = paste0("add_id",count), "ID", value=item)),
            div(textAreaInput(width=400, height=100, inputId = paste0("add_comment",count), "Value",value=value))
        )
      )
    )
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$dateList, {
    mydf <- myhist()[[input$dateList]]
    removeUI(selector = paste0("#add_update",addupdate()))
    count(0)
    addupdate(create_unique_id())
    insertUI(selector = "#mainupdate", where="beforeEnd", ui = div(id=paste0("add_update",addupdate())))
    lapply(1:nrow(mydf), function(row) {
      insertUI(selector = paste0("#add_update",addupdate()), where="beforeEnd", ui = add_item(count(),addupdate(), mydf[row,]$item, mydf[row,]$value))
      id <- paste0("gcs",count(),addupdate())
      idrm <- paste0("gcsrm",count(),addupdate())
      observeEvent(input[[id]], {
        removeUI(selector = paste0("#", idrm))
      })
      count(count()+1)
    })
  })
  
  create_unique_id <- function() {
    return(gsub('[:.]',"",unlist(strsplit(as.character(Sys.time()), "[ ]"))[2]))
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```